# Are the people asking questions citing engine analysis without giving a diagram the same person?

Tags: discussion, questions, users

They cite a game, describe a position in words, quote some inconclusive engine analysis, and ask for an answer. Examples:

- [Botvinnik vs Kholmov 1969: is the knight endgame riddle being solved?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41115/botvinnik-vs-kholmov-1969-is-the-knight-endgame-riddle-being-solved)
- [Did Leela miss a win in the following endgame ? Leela vs Dragon game](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41108/did-leela-miss-a-win-in-the-following-endgame-leela-vs-dragon-game)
- [An interesting question from a Leela vs Komodo blitz game](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39107/an-interesting-question-from-a-leela-vs-komodo-blitz-game) (diagram was edited into this question by someone else later)
- [A critical endgame in the French Winaver](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35487/a-critical-endgame-in-the-french-winaver) (diagram was also edited into this question by someone else)
- [A complex eight pieces opposite color Bishop endgame](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40986/a-complex-eight-pieces-opposite-color-bishop-endgame) (diagram edited into question)
- [Could Boleslavsky have won against Smyslov?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39335/could-boleslavsky-have-won-against-smyslov) (diagram edited into question)
- [Jobava vs Milton 2005 Skandemborg game](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37074/jobava-vs-milton-2005-skandemborg-game)
- [Did Leela miss a win in the following endgame?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41149/did-leela-miss-a-win-in-the-following-endgame)

Some of the questions are asked by "Stefano", but there are two separate accounts with that name. Other questions are asked by "user33339" and also "user27314".

Are they the same person, and if so, is there any plan to do something about the questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention! You're right, you don't really need moderator-only information to see that this is the same person. Stack Exchange has a rather strict quality system which prevents users from [posting too many poor questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232). I do not know if this user is deliberately creating new accounts to circumvent the ban (and even if I did, I wouldn't be allowed to share it), but in the future, please flag new questions like this for moderator attention, so that we can quickly deal with them.